# Mocking a function using unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to do unit testing of a function "check()" which calls another function "test()".

I want to mock test() and call a function mocked() in place of it.

Here is my code:

```
import unittest
import mock

def check():
    return test()
def test():
    return "test"

def mocked():
    return "mocked"

class CheckTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch(target='test.test', spec=True, new_callable=mocked)
    def test_test(self, mocked):
        self.assertEqual(check(), "mocked")




if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

All I want is to replace string returned by test() with my string. and I can not override or change test() or check() functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little bit simple: you can set `return_value` to do it:

```
import unittest
import mock

def check():
    return test()
def test():
    return "test"

class CheckTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('__main__.test')
    def test_test(self, mocked):
        mocked.return_value = "mocked"
        self.assertEqual(check(), "mocked")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

`mocked` is the mocked version of your `test` function.

Comment: @user3688148 If you use it from console you must use `__main__` instead the name module.

Comment: @user3688148 If you think it was useful you should click the up arrow too and not just accept it :)

Comment: I am new here, so I can not up vote you(at least 15 points required).